# Python IMAP - how to quickly test IMAP server connection

Tags: python, imap

I am working on email client, and now my goal is to come up with Thunderbird-like auto-configuration functionality. To do this, I am stuck at the following:

Imagine I have several possible values of the target IMAP server name, like

```
imap.mail1.com
imap.mail2.com
imap.mail3.com
```

and I have to test them one by one. It is important that I don't want to test the credentials (password). All I need is to understand that a given IMAP server name corresponds to a user mailbox.

I am using IMAPClient to power up my app, but I have got no idea how to test IMAP connection. It is important to mention that this test has to respond quickly, because I in real life I have hundreds of possible options, and I can't make the user wait for ages. Any help on this ?

UPDATE.

As for now, I check IMAP doing this:

```
incoming_server = 'imap.mail.ru'
server = IMAPClient(incoming_server, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
try:
    server.login(login, password)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    # Incorrect imap server
```

This seems like overkill because this works critically slow and it seems like I do not need the password just to figure out the IMAP server name. I am sure there's more "lightweight" way to "ping" the server

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using threads somehow?

Comment: @arnt, please see the updated question. No, I don't use threading. However, I would like to know how I can check IMAP without user's password

Comment: Well, and speed is the main concern

Comment: You can check whether there *is* an IMAP server, but you can't check that the user's mailbox is there without their password.

Comment: No, I can. Thunderbird did it somehow. I entered incorrect password, and it detected my imap and  smpt servers names just based on the mailbox name

Comment: It may have just used the first ones it found.  If you're sure, then good luck, since you seem to know better than me.

Comment: Thunderbird does a lot of DNS lookups and connections in parallel, santity-checking the results. Most good clients do much the same. Do DNS lookups of all the plausible names, weed out the implausible ones, connect to the remaining possibles, weed out the ones without plausible-looking IMAP servers, finally send login/pw to one or a few candidates.

Comment: Thunderbird, Outlook and other clients use autoconfiguration as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration to detect the right server configuration.